# Mysql exclude records

Tags: mysql, record

I have two tables, user and role, one user  can have more than 1 role

> ```
> user: ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | etc..
>        1 | PETER     | Blomp    | 
>
>
> role: ID |  ROLEID   | USERID (which is user ID)
>       70 |    5      |    1 (peter)
>       71 |    2      |    1
> ```

What I have to do and cant figure out is, how can retrieve data of users whos roleid is not
even to some integer, for. ex. user PETER can have roleID's 5 and 2, what i am trying to get is that IF Peter has roleid 3, he excludes from resultset, no matter if he has roleid 5.

Comment: You would use NOT IN (sub query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    user.ID, user.FirstName, user.LastName
FROM
    user
WHERE
    user.ID NOT IN (
                    SELECT ID FROM role WHERE role.RoleID = '3'
                   )
```

This uses whats known as a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html) in MySQL. The subquery in the WHERE clause will select all the IDs (such as Peter) who have a RoleID of 3. It will then exclude those ID's (Peter), using [`NOT IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in), from the selection of users.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `NOT IN`

```
select * from user inner join role on role.userid = user.id
user.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM role WHERE role.RoleID = '3')
```

Comment: If Peter has roles 3 and 5, this will still select Peter as role 5. User asked for it to not select Peter at all if role 3 is any one of  his roles.