# In MySQL, how do I select the latest articles EXCEPT for the last 3 articles

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL, when doing a query, how do I select the latest articles except for the last 3 articles? So, let's say I have 100 articles, and I want to select article number 97, 96, and 95; but not article number 98, 99 and 100.

But I need it to be dynamic. So if I insert 100 more articles in my database, then I would need articles number 197, 196 and 195.

What I have right now is this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, map, title, summary, video, date, publish, difficulty FROM articles WHERE publish = 1 AND map = 'MOVEMENT' AND id > 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
```

I think it's the `id > 1` that needs to be changed by some math count or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql exclude records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681889/mysql-exclude-records)

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause takes up to 2 arguments, the first being the offset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order your result by id, descending, get only 3 results and use 3 as offset.

In example :

```
SELECT id,
       map,
       title,
       summary,
       video,
       date,
       publish,
       difficulty
FROM articles
WHERE publish = 1
AND map = 'MOVEMENT'
AND id > 1
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3, 3;
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT),
                        (DEFAULT);
```

---

**Query #1 : Last id**

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS "Last id"
FROM test;
```

**Output**

```
| Last id |
| ------- |
| 19      |
```

---

**Query #2 Get the 3 lasts offset 3**

```
SELECT id
FROM test
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3, 3;
```

**Output**

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 16  |
| 15  |
| 14  |
```

---

**Query #3 Get the 3 lasts offset 3 and fix the order**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT id
  FROM test
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3, 3
) AS t
ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```

**Output**

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 14  |
| 15  |
| 16  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uCQ8AUVVmmLyEK9wr8Qmot/0)

Comment: The answer is correct, but a bit more explanation: `SELECT` normally orders id's from 1 - 100. `ORDER DESC` turns it upside down, ordering from 100 - 1. `LIMIT 3,3` means: skip the first 3 (start at nr 4) and then take 3.

Comment: @Michel I agree with you, you can edit my answer to add those informations, mines weren't that clear